# I am having troubles putting a child value from my firebase database inside of a label box in a cell in my tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a project, and its with firebase database and swift. I have it so the user can make a post (its my personal app, mainly a fun project) and it uploads on the table view fine. But inside of the table view cell, I have a label where the name suppose to go. Its a custom table view cell. I have that set up right as well.

The problem lies when I try and put the author name into the label cell. I have tried many things... and I can not figure this out.

I have two classes in my code. I know it may not be the best coding practices, and my code may not be the best -- but I'm learning.

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var currentuser:String = ""

class TweetViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    var authornamereference: String = ""
    var timelinepost:[String] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return timelinepost.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TweetTableViewCell
        cell.postcontenttext.text = self.timelinepost[indexPath.row]
        cell.postauthorlabel.text = self.authornamereference
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!

    func alertcreated (title:String, message:String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var possstkeystring:String = "author name"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        possstkeystring = "author"
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("User").child(userID!).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let userinfo = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = userinfo!["Name"] as! String
            self.NameLabel.text = username
            self.NameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps", size: 25)
            currentuser = self.NameLabel.text!
        }
        self.ref.child("All Post").observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
            var keyvalues: [String:Any] = [:]
            keyvalues = ["Post Content": item["Post Content"] as Any]
            self.timelinepost.append(keyvalues["Post Content"] as! String)
            self.mytableview.reloadData()
         }

        self.ref.child("All Post").child(self.possstkeystring).child("Post Author").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let item = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                self.authornamereference = item["Post Author"] as! String
            }
        })
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func addtweet(_ sender: UIButton) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "addnewpostsegue", sender: self)
    }    
}

class TestAddPost: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var postbuttonoutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func cancelbacktotimeline(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cancelpost", sender: self)
    }

    var officialpostkeyvalue = ""
    @IBAction func postbuttonaddpost(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postvalue =  ref.child("All Post").childByAutoId()
        let postkeyvalue = postvalue.key!
        postvalue.child("Post Content").setValue(postcontent.text)
        postvalue.child("Post Author").setValue(currentuser)
        officialpostkeyvalue = postkeyvalue
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addpostbacktotimeline", sender: self)    
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let tabCtrl = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let tweetviewcontroller = tabCtrl.viewControllers![0] as! TweetViewController
        tweetviewcontroller.possstkeystring = officialpostkeyvalue
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var postcontent: UITextView!
}
```

I know my variable names are not conventional or the way I programmed it may not be the best, but its working how I want it, its just the author name is not working..

How I have it set up is :

When the user clicks post --> it takes the name tag I have and store him as the author.. it then stores in firebase database in the tree format
"All Post" -> Random ID ->Author name 
"All Post" -> Random ID ->Post content

Then I try to retrieve the author name and put it inside of the label and nothing I do works. please help!